# Div have border-radius 100% need to set text in it

Tags: html, css

I have a div with border-radius 100% , and i have text in it is there any way to set text in circle of that div.

I have  paragraphs and Ul Li's in it the text goes out of the div area i need to wrap the text with border-radius of the div .

[image]

Comment: Will be possible when browsers will implement the `shape-inside` property([Isn't fully compatible yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-inside)).

Comment: in circle of that div or in center of that div??

Comment: Did you try to use: padding-left: [25% of width]; padding-left: [25% of height];padding-right: [25% of width];padding-bottom: [25% of height]; ? This would give you the inner rectangle of the shape.

Comment: <div style='border-radius:100%; background-color:#bcd; text-align:center'>aaaaa</div>

Comment: Could you give more details about the question please. It should be possible to set text within a div with 100% border-radius.

Comment: [See this for info](http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/)

Comment: @jbutler483 - If I understand the question properly, the OP wants to wrap the text in a circle.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: I was guessing they wanted the "text to go around in a circle" - but I could be misunderstanding the question altogether :S

Comment: http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit long winded, but you could possibly work with it (or create it in javascript):

```css
  .num1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 30px) rotate(-35deg);
  }
  .num2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 25px) rotate(-25deg);
  }
  .num3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 23px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  .num4 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 25px) rotate(25deg);
  }
  .num5 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 30px) rotate(35deg);
  }
  span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px;
  }
.circ{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;

    }
```

```html
<div class="circ">
  <span class="num1">a</span>
  <span class="num2">b</span>
  <span class="num3">c</span>
  <span class="num4">d</span>
  <span class="num5">e</span>
</div>
```

Also not: I've only prefixed for webkit browsers.

---

From your edit, You're looking to use something like the

```
-webkit-shape-inside
```

css property.

Since this isn't supported by the Likes of Firefox or IE (at all), I would advise you not to incorporate this *yet* until browser support is improved.

However, if you still wish to proceed, you might find an interesting read [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/shapes-module/)

- Another interesting read [would be this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/raggedfloat/demo.html)

Comment: #jbutler483 i know about this but i have edited my question please see the link attached in it i need text to represent like that

Comment: The use [this](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php)